How to remove corrupted flash from vc-02 module?
How to remove corrupted flash from vc-02 module? The flash size was 2MB but I went to upload 2.195 MB. So the upload stopped after it reached 93%. Since then, the firmware is not being uploaded in any way. But the module is showing on the computer and in the flash software with the port number.
I uploaded the firmware by connecting the USB data cable directly to the computer to the module.
I downloaded the UART burning tool from this https://docs.ai-thinker.com/en/voice_module and uploaded the firmware from there.
There is no erase button or other button in the software. There is just a start button written in Chinese.
Can anyone please solve this problem?
UART burning tools
My VC-02 module has 2MB flash size. But I went to upload a flash of 2.195MB size.
